# Why operator AND returns error in tsql, that seems to be valid in general sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I try to apply `WHERE AND WHERE` operators, but somehow `AND` returns an error, single `WHERE` for both cases works fine.

I don't feel like I made a mistake in code as well, at least not in general SQL syntax.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.flat_file
WHERE [Date] > '1/1/2020'
AND
WHERE [Deposit] > 1000
```

I am new to T-SQL, so I may not be aware of basic principles.

[tsql printscr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ounT.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can only be one `WHERE` clause in a query. You try to have two. Instead just `AND` the second condition to the first in the first (and only) `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *
       FROM dbo.flat_file
       WHERE [Date] > '1/1/2020'
             AND [Deposit] > 1000;
```

Side note: `varchar` is likely the wrong datatype for `date` and `deposit`. `date` and `integer` my be a better fit.